# ¿Cómo puedo invertir una matriz en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> ¿Cómo podría invertir una matriz en Python 3 para leerla de forma contraria
>   sin usar la función --> sopa=sopa[::-1] como se ve en el ejemplo?
>
> Lo quiero hacer de otra manera, pero no conozco otra forma.

```
def encuentra_maximo (sopa):

    num=-1
    dim=extrae_dimension(sopa)
    num=recorre_horizontal(sopa,dim,num)
    num=recorre_vertical(sopa,dim,num)
    sopa=sopa[::-1] #esta función invierte la matriz.
    num=recorre_horizontal(sopa,dim,num)
    num=recorre_vertical(sopa,dim,num)
return num
```

Espero que con este ejemplo me lo puedan resolver, Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Con "matriz" te refieres a una lista o usas NumPy? Como te comenta Luis Daniel deberías mostrar un ejemplo de que quieres hacer exactamente.  Puedes obtener iterador invertido mediante [reversed()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) en vez de crear una shadaw copy mediante slicing como comentas. Otra opción es iterar mediante `range` e indexado.

Comment: Con matriz me refiero a una lista si

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta ya te la dió FJSevilla en los comentarios. Lo que tu estás haciendo es esto:

```
sopa = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(sopa[::-1])
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Es una forma de "slicing" que revierte el orden de la lista, esto genera una nueva copia de la lista. La otra forma es usar [`reversed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) que retorna un `iterador`, algo muy útil si no necesitamos una copia de la lista original, pero si ese fuera el caso tenemos que convertir el `iterador` en una lista mediante `list()`.

```
print(list(reversed(sopa)))
['c', 'b', 'a']
```

Y por último recorriendo la lista del último al primer elemento usando comprensión de listas.

```
print([sopa[i] for i in range(len(sopa)-1, -1, -1)])
['c', 'b', 'a']
```